# web html template not able to overwrite

Tags: magento2, template, html

I'm trying to overwrite below html template file but not working. I have already run commands.

> vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\view\frontend\web\template\payment\discount.html

to

> app\design\frontend\Pt\name\Magento_SalesRules\web\template\payment\discount.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below method to override **.html** files:

Create a **requirejs-config.js** file from below path.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

And place below code in **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_SalesRule/template/payment/discount.html' : 'Vendor_Module/template/payment/discount.html'
        }
  }
};
```

Path of new discount.html will be like below:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/discount.html

So we can override any html file in this way.

Answer (score 6):

Just create or edit `requirejs-config.js` file from below path.

> app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

And place below code in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Payment/template/payment/cc-form.html': 
              'Namespace_Module/template/payment/cc-form.html'
        }
  }
};
```

So we can override any html file in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a typo

Try rename this:

```
  app\design\frontend\Pt\name\Magento_SalesRules\web\template\payment\discount.html
```

With this

```
  app\design\frontend\Pt\name\Magento_SalesRule\web\template\payment\discount.html
```